# Integrate Bootstrap Theme in Phoenix Framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, phoenix-framework

I have been building a Meteor app and decided to ditch it in favor of phoenix. The problem I am having is trying to integrate a pre-made Bootstrap theme with my app. I need to be able to control the load order of the CSS, Sass, and JavaScript. In Meteor you put the load order in a package.json file and build a custom package for it. Also, you don't have to include import statements in your HTML. So my specific questions are these:

How do I control the load order of the files?

Where should all the JavaScript, CSS, Sass, and images files go? (I'm guessing in the static vendor directory?)

I do need to include the import statements in the HTML files correct?

This theme is pretty big with a bunch of JavaScript files, font awesome, Bootstrap CSS, custom CSS, Sass, images, and the kitchen sink.

Answer (score 5):

In Phoenix this can be accomplished like so:

You'll want to include the **sass-brunch** package in your **package.json** file and run **npm-install** e.g.

```
{
  "repository": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "brunch": "^1.8.5",
    "babel-brunch": "^5.1.1",
    "clean-css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "javascript-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "sass-brunch": "^1.8.10",
    "uglify-js-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8"
  }
}
```

Now you'll change your **app.css** located **web/static/css/app.css** file to **app.scss**. From here import all of your css/sass files (I personally add bootstrap to the vendor folder under css **web/static/vendor/css/bootstrap.scss**) e.g.

```
@import "../vendor/css/bootstrap";
```

This next part might be the part that you had trouble figuring out, as I =o). What you do for javascript files is require them in your **brunch-config.js** file like so:

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js",
      order: {
        before: [
          "web/static/vendor/js/jquery.min.js",
          "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "web/static/vendor/js/scripts.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    // This option sets where we should place non-css and non-js assets in.
    // By default, we set this to "/web/static/assets". Files in this directory
    // will be copied to `paths.public`, which is "priv/static" by default.
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
    // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
    watched: [
      "deps/phoenix/web/static",
      "deps/phoenix_html/web/static",
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],

    // Where to compile files to
    public: "priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true
  }
};
```

Comment: You do include import statements and script src in the html.eex files right? To make sure I have this right, I need to change app.css to app.scss, add scss support in my brunch config, import all my css and scss files into app.scss, and put all the css and js files into the vendor folder.  Does that sound right?

Comment: That's right ceero, by doing it this way you will be able to import them in the order that the theme needs to have the files imported. As for the html.eex file you won't need to import or link to the files individually because phoenix working along with brunch will compile and compress all the files into one css and one js file for you by using brunch build and when you're getting ready to push to production you will want to run mix phoenix.digest which will digest your assets for you.

Comment: Those files are already linked to in your main layout file app.html.eex file which is located in web/templates/layout.

Comment: Got it.  That was the explanation I was looking for.  Does Phoenix allow you to use multiple layouts depending on the route?

Comment: It does ceero, you can see how thats implemented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399767/proper-way-to-use-different-layouts-for-templates-in-phoenix/33400578#33400578 and here http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.0.0/Phoenix.Controller.html#layout/1